# In Word 365, customize the icon shown in quick access for commands without specific icon

Tags: microsoft-word, icons

In Word 365 I've added "Go to Next Page" and "Go to Previous Page" to my Quick Access. The problem is, they have the same nonspecific icon.
In the "Customize the Quick Access Toolbar", the "Modify.." button is greyed out.

Is there any way to **modify those icons** ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try the steps below：

1.Click Customize Ribbon.

2.In the Customize the Ribbon window, under the Customize the Ribbon list, click the custom group or command that you added.

3.Click Rename, and then in the Symbol list, click an icon.

4.In the Rename dialog box, click OK.

5.To see and save your customizations, click OK.

[image]

Comment: unfortunately the icons created that way can't be added to the Quick Access.  But I take it as a partial solution as I can just place the icons on my home tab instead as on the quick access.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "Go To..." commands, there are now "Next Page" and "Previous Page" commands you can add to the Quick Access Toolbar. These have up-arrow and down-arrow icons.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the same command. the "Go To" commands will move the cursor, the "next page" commands will only move the visualization, but not the cursor. And they won't reset the  behaviour of Ctrl+PgUp / Ctrl+PgDn